# Publishing MXD through ArcPy, Without Opening ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-server, mxd

I currently have to have ArcMap open and the connection to my ArcGIS server established in catalog to run my script which publishes MXD files.

```
con = r'C:\...\myserver.ags'
arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', con, True, serverFolder)
analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForSD(sddraft)
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to cut out the part of having to have ArcMap open and manually turning on the server connection. Perhaps connecting some socket or something?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [CreateMapSDDocument](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm), `map_document`, is:

> A variable that references a MapDocument object. The data frame that
>   was active at the time the map_document was saved will be published.

Consequently, I would expect this would work:

```
mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(PATH TO YOUR MXD)
arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', con, True, serverFolder
```

If not perhaps you can expand your snippet to include that and tell us what happens when that is run.